# DNX Error when running webapplication, ideas?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dnx, dnvm

i just installed a new empty ASP.NET 5 WebApplication and got this error when running the app via IISExpress. Any idea what the problem is?

> Could not load file or assembly 'dnx.clr.managed' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Description:
>   An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
>   web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in the code. Exception Details:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'dnx.clr.managed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find
>   the file specified. Source Error: An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding
>   the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the
>   exception stack trace below. Assembly Load Trace: The following
>   information can be helpful to determine why the assembly
>   'dnx.clr.managed' could not be loaded.
>   === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = dnx.clr.managed  (Partial) WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an
>   assembly: WRN: Assembly Name: dnx.clr.managed | Domain ID: 3 WRN: A
>   partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is
>   provided. WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect
>   assembly. WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual
>   identity for the assembly, WRN: that consists of the simple name,
>   version, culture, and public key token. WRN: See whitepaper
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and
>   common solutions to this issue. LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///C:/Users/Admin/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta7/bin
>   LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL Calling assembly : (Unknown).
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Configuration file C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe.config does not
>   exist. LOG: No application configuration file found. LOG: Using host
>   configuration file:
>   C:\Users\Admin\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config LOG: Using
>   machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private,
>   custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind). LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/Admin/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta7/bin/dnx.clr.managed.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/Admin/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta7/bin/dnx.clr.managed/dnx.clr.managed.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/Admin/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta7/bin/dnx.clr.managed.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/Admin/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta7/bin/dnx.clr.managed/dnx.clr.managed.EXE.

Here is my project.json

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta6"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ]
}
```

Dnx versions installed

```
       1.0.0-beta5       clr     x64          C:\Users\Admin\.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-beta5       clr     x86          C:\Users\Admin\.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-beta5       coreclr x64          C:\Users\Admin\.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-beta5       coreclr x86          C:\Users\Admin\.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-beta6       clr     x64          C:\Users\Admin\.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-beta6       clr     x86          C:\Users\Admin\.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-beta6       coreclr x64          C:\Users\Admin\.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-beta6       coreclr x86          C:\Users\Admin\.dnx\runtimes
  *    1.0.0-beta7       clr     x86          C:\Users\Admin\.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x86          C:\Users\Admin\.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 coreclr x86          C:\Users\Admin\.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-rc2-16249   clr     x86          C:\Users\Admin\.dnx\runtimes
```

Answer (score 2):

You declare dependencies on `beta6` but use `dnx beta7`, you should update your dependencies to last stable release `1.0.0-rc1-update1` and use it.

Set also the alias default on `1.0.0-rc1-update1`:

dnvm commands

```
 dnvm alias default 1.0.0-rc1-update1 -a x86 -r clr

 dnvm use default
```

`Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS` doesn't exist for `rc1`, replace it by  `Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler`

project.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
},
```

You might also uninstall old beta versions and update dnvm to the latest stable version.